# Using PHP and XPATH, how would you get the contents of the closest `h3`?

Tags: php, html, xpath, domdocument

- Using PHP and XPATH, how would you correctly get the text of the closest `h3` tag containing the date of the Stoke City vs. Crystal palace match? (e.g. Saturday 4 October)
- In essence I am searching for the match date and my inputs are the home team and the away team
- HTML snippet listing 4 (out of the remaining 321) English Premier League Football fixtures for the 2014/15 season

  ```
  <div class="fixtures">
      <h3>Monday 29 September</h3>
      <dl class="matches">
          <dt class="match">
              <span class="match-time">20:00</span>
              <span class="home-side">
                  <span>
                      <img src="http://omo.akamai.opta.net/image.php?&amp;sport=football&amp;entity=team&amp;description=badges&amp;dimensions=20&amp;id=110" alt="Stoke City">
                  </span>
                  <a href="http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sport/teampages/stoke-city.html">Stoke City</a>
              </span>
              <span>
                  <span>&nbsp;</span>
                  <span>vs</span>
                  <span>&nbsp;</span>
              </span>
              <span class="away-side">
                  <span>
                      <img src="http://omo.akamai.opta.net/image.php?&amp;sport=football&amp;entity=team&amp;description=badges&amp;dimensions=20&amp;id=4" alt="Newcastle United">
                  </span>
                  <a href="http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sport/teampages/newcastle-united.html">Newcastle United</a>
              </span>
          </dt>
      </dl>
      <dl class="matches">
          <dt class="match">
              <span class="match-time">15:00</span>
              <span class="home-side">
                  <span>
                      <img src="http://omo.akamai.opta.net/image.php?&amp;sport=football&amp;entity=team&amp;description=badges&amp;dimensions=20&amp;id=13" alt="Leicester City">
                  </span>
                  <a href="http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sport/teampages/leicester.html">Leicester City</a>
              </span>
              <span>
                  <span>&nbsp;</span>
                  <span>vs</span>
                  <span>&nbsp;</span>
              </span>
              <span class="away-side">
                  <span>
                      <img src="http://omo.akamai.opta.net/image.php?&amp;sport=football&amp;entity=team&amp;description=badges&amp;dimensions=20&amp;id=90" alt="Burnley">
                  </span>
                  <a href="http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sport/teampages/burnley.html">Burnley</a>
              </span>
          </dt>
      </dl>              
      <h3>Saturday 4 October</h3>
      <dl class="matches">
          <dt class="match">
              <span class="match-time">15:00</span>
              <span class="home-side">
                  <span>
                      <img src="http://omo.akamai.opta.net/image.php?&amp;sport=football&amp;entity=team&amp;description=badges&amp;dimensions=20&amp;id=14" alt="Liverpool">
                  </span>
                  <a href="http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sport/teampages/liverpool.html">Liverpool</a>
              </span>
              <span>
                  <span>&nbsp;</span>
                  <span>vs</span>
                  <span>&nbsp;</span>
              </span>
              <span class="away-side">
                  <span>
                      <img src="http://omo.akamai.opta.net/image.php?&amp;sport=football&amp;entity=team&amp;description=badges&amp;dimensions=20&amp;id=35" alt="West Bromwich Albion">
                  </span>
                  <a href="http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sport/teampages/west-bromwich-albion.html">West Bromwich Albion</a>
              </span>
          </dt>
      </dl>            
      <dl class="matches">
          <dt class="match">
              <span class="match-time">15:00</span>
              <span class="home-side">
                  <span>
                      <img src="http://omo.akamai.opta.net/image.php?&amp;sport=football&amp;entity=team&amp;description=badges&amp;dimensions=20&amp;id=110" alt="Stoke City">
                  </span>
                  <a href="http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sport/teampages/stoke-city.html">Stoke City</a>
              </span>
              <span>
                  <span>&nbsp;</span>
                  <span>vs</span>
                  <span>&nbsp;</span>
              </span>
              <span class="away-side">
                  <span>
                      <img src="http://omo.akamai.opta.net/image.php?&amp;sport=football&amp;entity=team&amp;description=badges&amp;dimensions=20&amp;id=31" alt="Crystal Palace">
                  </span>
                  <a href="http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sport/teampages/crystal-palace.html">Crystal Palace</a>
              </span>
          </dt>
      </dl>          
  </div>
  ```

Comment: is this structure always going to be the same?

Comment: Yep - just repeats itself. e.g. `div.fixtures` then `h3` or 1 or more `dl.matches`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this XPath :

```
//h3[following-sibling::dl[1][.//span[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' home-side ') and span/img[@alt='Hull City']]]]
```

Basically, above XPath select `<h3>` element having next sibling `<dl>` element containing a `<span class="home-side">` and another `<span>` with `<img alt="Hull City">` (formatted version) :

```
//h3[
        following-sibling::dl[1][
                    .//span[
                        contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' home-side ') 
                            and 
                        span/img[@alt='Hull City']
                    ]
        ]
    ]
```

**UPDATE :**

Following is an XPath example that checks for both home team and away team :

```
//h3[
        following-sibling::dl[1][
                    .//span[
                        contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' home-side ') 
                            and 
                        span/img[@alt='Hull City']
                    ]
                        and
                    .//span[
                        contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' away-side ') 
                            and 
                        span/img[@alt='Crystal Palace']
                    ]
        ]

    ]
```

**UPDATE 2 :**

To be able to account multiple `<dl>`s, I think it will be easier to find `<dl>` that satisfies home and away team criteria first, then move backward to find closest `<h3>` element from such `<dl>` :

```
//dl[
        .//span[
            contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' home-side ') 
                and 
            span/img[@alt='Stoke City']
        ]
            and
        .//span[
            contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' away-side ') 
                and 
            span/img[@alt='Crystal Palace']
        ]
    ]/preceding-sibling::h3[1]
```

Comment: Your answer actually helps with another issue I have which is extending my query to define the away-side: `[.//span[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' away-side ') and span/img[@alt='West Bromwich Albion']]]`. How would I include this in your suggested query? Thanks

Comment: Another thing I didn't mention is that the `<h3>` will sometimes refer to multiple `<dl>`s such that you could have: `<h3>` then `<dl>` then `<dl>` then `<h3>` then `<dl>`. Will update my question

Comment: And what you want to happen in case there are multiple `<dl>`s? XPath in this answer only check the closest `<dl>` ...

Comment: It would have to traverse up until it found the closest `<h3>` before the `<dl>` as a sibling - see HTML snippet for examples. e.g. Stoke City vs. Crystal Palace should give Saturday 4 October

Comment: @u01jmg3 check **UPDATE 2** section

Answer (score 1):

If the structure is always going to be the same, you could point it first to that img tag with that alt value, then traverse it backwards.

Example:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($markup);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$needle = 'Hull City';
$element = $xpath->query("//span/img[contains(@alt, '$needle')]");
if($element->length > 0) {
    $img = $element->item(0);
    $header = $xpath->query('ancestor::node()/preceding-sibling::h3[1]', $img);
    if($header->length > 0) {
        echo $header->item(0)->nodeValue; // Saturday 4 October
    }
}
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/BaT4dP)

Comment: My recommendation would be to drop the `[4]`. It just creates a higher dependency on the document structure and isn't needed.

Comment: @JLRishe thats a good recommendation  on your part, thanks for this insight

Comment: Works well so thanks but the suggestion by @har07 looks like it will allow me to also define the away-side in the same query.

Comment: @Ghost: what happens if the `<h3>` is for multiple matches such that you have `<h3>` then `<dl>` then `<dl>`? e.g. How to get the match date for the Leicester City home game in my snippet?

Comment: @u01jmg3 yes it still accounts to that, since it find the preceding `<h1>` so it looks backwards, and then that `[1]` gets the first `<h3>`, [demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/QVxcqG)

Comment: Spot on. My final question (sorry!) is how do I also define the away-side in the query as well as the home-side?

Comment: @u01jmg3 before that, how are you going to feed it anyway? maybe just put an or inside the first xpath query on getting the `<img>`

Comment: Feed it? I think I know what you mean but for clarity I have updated the HTML snippet to show two home games for Stoke City. For this example lets say I am only interested in getting the match date for the one against Crystal Palace. At the moment your query would return just the first Stoke City match it finds.

Comment: @u01jmg3 oh okay, so the important thing its, you're always going to feed it with one team at a time, but this one team can have multiple date matches? is this correct? well you could just loop them, i just explicitly pointed to `->item(0)` since you didn't say thats going  to be the case. anyways, here is a demo http://codepad.viper-7.com/Gvx4gX

Comment: No (and yes I am not being clear). Let me try again: I will know the home team and away team and all I want to do is query the fixture list written in HTML to discover the match date. I then move on and do the same again with a new home and away team - this is taken care of in the form of a for loop which then surrounds the XPATH query you have provided.

Comment: @u01jmg3 so basically you're searching for match date, and your form inputs are the home team and the away team. is this correct? so basically you have two needles

Comment: Yes - I will define this in my question for more clarity